# Permutation composition with $n$-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Consider the set $\Pi$ of permutations $\pi: [n] \to [n]$ where each such $\pi$ is an $n$-cycle (i.e., one big cycle consisting of all elements). We know $|\Pi| = (n-1)!$.

I am interested in composing elements of $\Pi$ with an arbitrary permutation $\rho$, i.e., I am looking for some structure of the set $\Pi(\rho)=\{\pi \circ \rho \mid \pi \in \Pi\}$ in terms of some structure of $\rho$. Of course, assuming $n$ is even, the parity of $\rho$ determines the parity of $\pi \circ \rho$. But I do not think this set $\Pi(\rho)$ can be an arbitrary set of $(n-1)!$ permutations with the same parity (for some $\rho$). Is there something known about this (even when assuming some structure of $\rho$)?

An easier question would be to assume $\rho$ as some $k$-cycle ($k \leq n$). In that case, is there something known about the structure of $\Pi(\rho)$?

Comment: Is this related to yesterdays codeforces problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea about codeforces.

Comment: Oh ok my bad haha, it was extremely closely related to this, but that problem was only solvable due to some kind of troll extra constraints. https://codeforces.com/contest/1553/problem/E

Comment: Have you tried working through a smallish example, e.g., $n=4$?

Comment: Yes, did it for one such $\rho$. Unfortunately, did not get intuition. Maybe writing a code to enumerate over all $\rho$ will help. But before doing that, I wanted to know if something is already known.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49287/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4205497/14578.    Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: OK, I've worked through $S_4$. If $\rho$ is a transposition, you get four 3-cycles and two elements of the form $(ab)(cd)$. If $\rho$ is a 3-cycle, you get three transpositions and three 4-cycles. If $\rho$ is a 4-cycle, you get four 3-cycles, an $(ab)(cd)$, and the identity. If $\rho$ is an $(ab)(cd)$, you get four transpositions and two 4-cycles.